# Firebase update database auto push key generated twice?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a very strange bug. I am updating a firebase database reference by calling update() on the reference. Before I call update I ask firebase for a random key using push().key on my database reference. Like the below.

```
push().key
```

I have a button that triggers the update function and it does indeed update my reference but for some strange reason although the button triggers this function only once (I've logged the calling of the function and it is defo only called once) it's creating 2 autoId keys and duplicating the database entry. As I said the button triggers once but the reference is getting updated twice. So I have 2 entries as opposed to one.

Here is my function that gets called when my button is clicked.

```
function saveTimesheetEntry(weekNo, hours, payrate, type, theId) {

    console.log("Week Number: " + weekNo);
    console.log("Hours: " + hours);
    console.log("Pay Rate: " + payrate);

    var amount = hours * payrate;
    var vat = amount / 100 * 20; 

    console.log("Amount: " + amount);
    console.log("VAT: " + vat);
    console.log("Type: " + type);

    var autoId = contractorRef.push().key; // This is the generation of the key

    databaseRoot.ref('contractors-test/' + userObject.uid + '/timesheets-sub/weeks/'+weekNo).update({
        [autoId]:{ // Here I am using the generated key but its creating 2 separate entries in the db
            "hours":hours,
            "payRate":payrate,
            "amount":amount,
            "vat":vat,
            "type":type,
            "status":"submitted"
        }
    });

    databaseRoot.ref('contractors-test/' + userObject.uid + '/timesheets-sub/weeks').once('value', function(snapshot){

        $('#status-'+theId).removeClass("label-danger");
        $('#status-'+theId).addClass("label-warning");
        $('#status-'+theId).text("Submitted");
        $('#submitted-ts').html("");
        layoutSubTimeSheets(snapshot);

    });
}
```

As you can see I ask firebase for an autoId and then use that as my key but I am getting 2 auto keys and thus 2 database entries using the above object.

Comment: From a quick look it seems that this code is fine: each run of the function should update the database only once. The syntax you're using is a bit convoluted - I'd use `autoId` in the call to `child()` instead of in the value - but that shouldn't cause two children (in fact, it more likely results in too few values than in too many). Can you reproduce the problem in a jsbin, so I can have a look?

Comment: Is it possible you've double-registered an event handler somehow?

Comment: I figured it out. I did actually have the function get called twice in close succession. @FrankvanPuffelen do you recommend changing the update call to databaseRoot.ref('contractors-test/' + userObject.uid + '/timesheets-sub/weeks/'+weekNo+'/'+autoId) and just have the values in the object? Thanks for your help also!

Comment: An `update()` call loops over the object you pass in. For each key it **sets** the value you provide. So in your case, any data under `autoId` would still be replaced. If that is the intent, your code is fine. If you'd like existing properties under `autoId` to be retained, make sure you pass the `autoId` in the key so that the loop happens lower in the tree.